# User Programmed Key Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, key-bindings

Note, this is a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52045027/allow-users-to-override-key-bindings?noredirect=1&lq=1).

I have implemented a class that contains the key bindings as well as a "form" to allow the user to change the key bindings.  This works - key bindings get updated and work to implement the appropriate command.  However, it is very tedious and seems inefficient.  Basically, I have created a property for the `Key`'s and the `Modifier`'s:

```
private Key _changeBackgroundKey;
/// <summary>
/// Key to change the color of the background
/// </summary>
public Key ChangeBackgroundKey
{
    get { return _changeBackgroundKey; }
    set
    {
        if (_changeBackgroundKey == value)
            return;

        _changeBackgroundKey = value;
        OnPropertyChange(nameof(ChangeBackgroundKey));
    }
}

private ModifierKeys _changeBackgroundModifier;
/// <summary>
/// Key modifier to change the color of the background
/// </summary>
public ModifierKeys ChangeBackgroundModifier
{
    get { return _changeBackgroundModifier; }
    set
    {
        if (_changeBackgroundModifier == value)
            return;

        _changeBackgroundModifier = value;
        OnPropertyChange(nameof(ChangeBackgroundModifier));
    }
}
```

where `OnPropertyChange` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

The XAML is bound:

```
<KeyBinding Key="{Binding ChangeBackgroundKey}" Modifiers="{Binding ChangeBackgroundModifier}" Command="{Binding Settings.ChangeBackgroundColorCommand}"/>
```

This is done for **EACH** key binding I want to implement - I have to create a property for the `Key` and the `ModifierKeys`, bind them in the XAML, and update logic accordingly.  Is there a better/more efficient way of doing this?  While, my dummy project only is using four key bindings, my real application uses many more.